# Does ConfigurationPropertyCollection need to be static?

Tags: c#, .net, configuration

According to this oft-referenced article, [Unraveling the Mysteries of .NET Configuration](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/mysteriesofconfiguration.aspx), when implementing a ConfigurationSection / ConfigurationElement, it is recommended to follow this pattern:

```
private static ConfigurationPropertyCollection s_properties;
static ExampleSection()
{
        // Predefine properties here
        // Add the properties to s_properties
}

/// Override the Properties collection and return our custom one.
protected override ConfigurationPropertyCollection Properties
{
    get { return s_properties; }
}
```

But it does not explain *why* the `s_properties` field would need to be static, and the properties initialized in a static constructor.
After all, it's only accessed via the non-static `Properties` overridden property...

(I have a complicated set of custom configuration management, it would greatly simplify things having the `s_properties` field be NOT static...)

So, is there some "hidden" access directly to the static field? Is the `Configuration***` object continually created and re-created, such that object-level fields would be lost, and as such is inefficient?
Or is it perfectly fine to store and initialize the `ConfigurationPropertyCollection` as non-static?

Comment: @svick, yes I have tried it, and it *seems* to work fine. However, I don't know what is going on "under the covers", and if this has effect on performance. So perhaps the real question is "why does the article use static"...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But it does not explain why the s_properties field would need to be static,

The reason `s_properties` is static is because <strike>you</strike> the developer only wanted one set - a singleton instance - of configuration properties for an application. [*And this may be considered typical*.] The ConfigurationXXX (ConfigurationManager, for example) classes are static because you should only require one per AppDomain.

Basically, in the sample:

```
private static ConfigurationPropertyCollection s_properties;
static ExampleSection()
{
        // Predefine properties here
        // Add the properties to s_properties
}

/// Override the Properties collection and return our custom one.
protected override ConfigurationPropertyCollection Properties
{
    get { return s_properties; }
}
```

the author is assuming you should only have a single instance of `s_properties`.

> So, is there some "hidden" access directly to the static field?

Not sure I follow this question.

> Is the Configuration*** object continually created and re-created, such that object-level fields would be lost, and as such is inefficient?

[Edit: *Depends ... I was considering the ConfigurationManager. But, say I wanted to have a local copy of my AppSettingsCollection. I would make that a static readonly field declaration. In the context of Sections, etc. Then I would still use a static field inializer, albeit a `static Dictionary<string, ConfigurationPropertyCollection> Properties`. In the end, I still believe that you would only ever want a single instance of your property settings collection.*]

[Original with other [*edits*] ]
No. [*Static*] ConfigurationXXX objects are not continually created, disposed, and re-created. Like all static objects, a public static initializer/constructor is executed a single time - the first time that object is called. For instance, when I call the following:

```
string someValue = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SomeKey"];
```

The static `ConfigurationManager` class constructor is executed. Since this class is static, it will live for the lifetime of the current AppDomain in which it is executed.

I would not recommend initializing app domain properties, configuration properties, or property collections as <strike>or within</strike> an instance class. When your program begins execution, you should rely on a static Configuration class in which you wrap and customize interaction with ConfigurationXXX classes, members, and functions.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but there is a problem with it: the ConfigurationSection and ConfigurationElement classes are *not* static, in fact the `...ConfigurationPropertyCollection Properties` has to be non-static, as it is overriding the corresponding property from the non-static base property. So the rest of the answer doesnt make sense to me, either.

Comment: FTR, I agree that usually you should only have a single instance of each configuration class (unless, of course, you have more than one of it...)

Comment: @AviD is is completely reasonable to have multiple instance of a `ConfigurationElement` (eg. a collection). It is less likely but still possible to have multiple instances of a `ConfigurationSection` (two groups in a `.config` set up with same structure).

Comment: @Richard, well I was agreeing with @IAbstract statement, we were referring to initializing the class, properties, etc... Sorry I wasnt clear.

Comment: @AviD: I've edited a bit to support or explain my answers  ;)

Comment: Ah, I see - you were talking about ConfigurationManager, where I was referring to ConfigurationSection/Element. But what you say still stands wrt the config properties collection - i.e. you only want one. Right, thats what static is... But I was asking, if I only expect to create a single instance of the (non-static) ConfigSection/Element, is there any reason the properties still needs to be static? Thanks!

Comment: @AviD: The ultimate goals are that the process works as expected; that the process is maintainable; that the process is not brittle. So ... ultimately, the decision is yours. I work with utilities a lot so i am never sure what some application may be doing. I will typically make collections available via static properties or members. ;)

Comment: @IAbstract, but in this case we're talking specifically about the configuration framework - the question is there a requirement for it by the framework. So far, I'm understanding that it's not the case?

Comment: @AviD: As far as I can tell, nothing preventing you from instancing the collection, i.e. *not* static.

Comment: Thanks, "as far as I can tell" was me too, I was hoping for something a little more... authoritative. But I guess thats the way it is, hard to prove a negative. :)